# How to implement OAuth login on Roku

Tags: authentication, oauth, auth0, roku

Roku says [here](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/authentication/on-device-authentication.md) "Authentication via a third-party OAuth provider such as Google or Facebook is not supported."

But does that mean there is no way for us to provide OAuth login on Roku?
There must be at least something?

Are there no channels on Roku that have a Google or Facebook or some other login that is OAuth-based?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. There is no web browser on Roku.

Usually process is called "rendez-vous" auth, where a code is displayed on the TV and you activate it from web.

Unfortunately anyway, as a further constraint, rendez-vous login is now completely forbidden on Roku, unless you're signing in with a TV provider. You must offer email/password registration and login directly within the app.

Comment: Thanks Philippe !
But then how does Hulu, Youtube, Netflix are able to do the rendezvous login on Roku ?
Only because they are big names and maybe they have an "arrangement" with Roku ?

Comment: Roku Pay has been increasingly enforced, and now rendez-vous was clarified as also being not allowed. Of course older projects and big names may still have it, but even them may have to eventually bow to the stricter rules.